# Embedding Javascript With Script Tags

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to make this code work.

```
<script>
document.write('<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Sunnyvale",
    "addressRegion": "CA",
    "postalCode": "94086",
    "streetAddress": "1901 Lemur Ave"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4",
    "reviewCount": "250"
  },
  "name": "GreatFood",
  "openingHours": [
    "Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30",
    "Mo-Th 17:00-21:30",
    "Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00"
  ],
  "priceRange": "$$",
  "servesCuisine": [
    "Middle Eastern",
    "Mediterranean"
  ],
  "telephone": "(408) 714-1489",
  "url": "http://www.dishdash.com"
}
</script>')
</script>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to embed schema (JSON-LD) code on 3rd party properties where I have limited access to HTML. Right now the HTML gets broken up with `<br>` tags.

Comment: in the past, when `document.write` was still cool (i.e., in the 90's), script tags output by `document.write` had to be broken up ... like `document.write("<scr" + "ipt ...</scr" + "ipt>")`

Comment: I didn't realize that @Jaromanda X but what is the way to handle it now?